# Is there a better way to handle AJAX file downloads with Django?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, post

I am pretty new to web development in general; I am kind of learning everything on the fly. I recently got a Django application up and running, but I feel pretty dirty/hacky the way I did things.

**Problem:** User needs to input (potentially) a lot of data into an Excel-like spreadsheet on my webpage. I currently am using Handsontable for this. I then need to take the data, run some queries on it, process the results, and return an Excel sheet to the user.

Since the Handsontable is rendered via Javascript on page load, and not by Django, I needed to figure out a work around for getting the data into my views.py (I also couldn't strictly use AJAX because I could not figure out how to send the file to the browser once the request was completed).

**Current solution:** I have a Django Textarea hidden. When the user submits the form, I have a Javascript function dump the Handsontable into it in JSON form. Then in my views.py I parse the JSON, and do what I need to do with it, and return the Excel file to the user. Having a hidden field to get around all of this just doesn't seem right.

Is there a better way to send Django information and still have it handle the response? Like I said above, using AJAX worked great until the very end - when I had to serve the file to the user *without* having them click an extra link (or other work-arounds I've seen).

Comment: Why dont you put the handsontable part into a form and parse that in your view in the post response?

Comment: @ger.s.brett I definitely think I have a pretty large misunderstanding on how the forms in Django work - how can I access the data in the form that has not been rendered by Django?

Comment: It does not matter if django renders the form or you create it yourself. When the submit button on the form is pressed, everything between the form tags will be sent to django and you can evaluate it there.